# Mistake in integration by parts

Tags: calculus, integration

The partial integration rule says: $\int f'g=fg-\int fg'$ . If I use the rule for $f'(x)=2x,g(x)=\frac{1}{x^2}$, I get that:

\begin{align}\int\frac{1}{x^2}2x\,dx& =\frac{1}{x^2}x^2-\int\frac{-2}{x^3}x^2\,dx,\\
\int\frac{2}{x}\,dx& =1+\int\frac{2}{x}\,dx
\end{align}
and from this equation I get that $0=1$

Where did I make a mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How exactly do you get $1=0$?
I mean you have

$\int \underbrace{\frac{1}{x^2}}_{=x^{-2} = g}\underbrace{2x}_{=f'}\,dx$

and by partial integration this is

$\int f'(x) g(x)\,dx = fg - \int f(x)g'(x)\,dx$.

As you stated
$f = x^2 \Rightarrow fg = 1$. It remains to compute $\int f(x)g'(x)\,dx$.

The derivative of $g$ is (as you stated) $g'(x) = -2x^{-3}$. Therefore you have

$\int f(x)g'(x)\,dx = \int x^2 (-2x^{-3})\,dx = \int -2x^{-1}\,dx$.

Do you know what the antiderivative of this thing is?

Comment: @Thomaschen - Out of curiousity, how did this answer your question? There is no information in this post that differs in any way from what you had already showed in your question. It gives no clue at all that I can see as to your mistake (which Umberto has correctly addressed).

Answer (score 14):

The mistake is thinking that antiderivatives are unique. The fact that $(x^2 + 1)' = (x^2 + 0)'$ does not imply $1 = 0$.

In the case of the integration by parts formula, you can avoid the nonuniqueness issue  if you use definite integrals. You will have $$\int_a^b \frac{1}{x^2} 2x \, dx = \left.1 \right|_a^b - \int_a^b \frac{-2}{x^3}x^2 \, dx$$
where $1|_a^b = 1 - 1 = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

When dealing with antiderivatives in a purely formal way, you're always working modulo an element of the kernel of the derivation operator, that is modulo a constant.

If you call C the set of constants and F the set of differentiable functions, then you effectively have 0=1 in the quotient set F/C.